# iPhone Simulator immediately crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator, exc-bad-access, nsautoreleasepool

I immediately get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

in iPhone Simulator on `@autoreleasepool`. I tried running in Debug and in Release mode. The app runs perfectly fine on my iPad. I run both iPad and Simulator on iOS 5.0.

I enabled everything I know about XCode Debugging and all i get is this log which does not help me at all:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Thu Nov  3 21:59:02 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Setting environment variable "DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES" to null value.
Setting environment variable "MallocGuardEdges" to null value.
Setting environment variable "MallocStackLogging" to null value.
Setting environment variable "MallocScribble" to null value.
Setting environment variable "AUTO_LOG_ALL" to null value.
Setting environment variable "DYLD_PRINT_APIS" to null value.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1935.
dyld: loaded: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/E0BFA392-7C53-4A31-9F0A-36EB5DD15E6F/Tests.app/Tests
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.override.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcache_sim.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto_sim.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libnotify_sim.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_dnssd.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_info.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libxpc_sim.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libLLVMContainer.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libresolv.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreData.framework/CoreData
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageCapture.framework/ImageCapture
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks//CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUI.framework/SpringBoardUI
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BulletinBoard.framework/BulletinBoard
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/ToneLibrary
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
Catchpoint 4 (throw)Pending breakpoint 1 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
Pending breakpoint 3 - ""main_test.m":13" resolved
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

The only thing that looks a bit strange to me is

```
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
```

Of course did I also reset simulator, deleted all build directories, cleaned my project, restarted XCode and even rebooted my Mac. Nothing helps...

Any hints on this?

Comment: Probably something amiss with your app delegate or your MainWindow -- that's what I would check.  Do you have a mainwindow assigned?  What does your AppDelegate look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds clearly that one or more dependencies will be wrong referenced. For example if you don't have an universal framework or library.

Control your frameworks and eventually add them once manually again.

Check your frameworks with lipo and otool.

for example: `otool -hv Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20.a`

or: `lipo -info Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20.a`